# Independently publishing a non-fiction, self-help book and would like to include anonymous case studies

Tags: non-fiction

I will interview and receive verbal acknowledgement of the recording.  All of the people who are interviewed will be anonymous. Do I need them to sign any type of consent? I will send them a copy of any excerpts used in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to abide by current ethical standards for scientific research, you need to explain the purpose of your research and what they will have to do during their participation to each of your participants, and everyone has to sign an agreement that allows you to use their data for that purpose. In some countries (e.g. in the European Union), you will also have to assure them that all data will be anonymized and that you will delete their data once your research is finished. You must give them all this information in written form as well as explain it verbally.

You will find more detailed information if you search the internet for "principles / standards for ethical research" and your jurisdiction or institution. All universities that I know of publish their ethical standards, so you can look at them online.